# $|\mathbf{b}| \leq \sqrt{37}$ cuts the join of $5\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}$ and $5\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}$ in what ratio?

Tags: vectors

> If $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector whose initial point divides the join of $5 \hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}$ and $5 \hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}$ in the ratio $k/1$ and whose terminal point is at the origin and
> $|\mathbf{b}| \leq \sqrt{37}$, then $k$ lies in the interval ...

I tried solving it but I couldn't. I will share my attempt tomorrow cause I'm too tired now. It's $12$am.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [8.  Proof by lack of sufficient time](https://themathlab.com/geometry/funnyproofs.htm) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point that divides $5\mathbf{i}$ and $5\mathbf{j}$ in the ratio
$\frac{k}{1}$ is:

$$\mathbf{b}=\frac{(5\mathbf{j})k+(5\mathbf{i})1}{k+1}$$

therefore

$$\mathbf{b}=\frac{(5\mathbf{i})+(5k\mathbf{j})}{k+1}$$

But $|\mathbf{b}| \leq \sqrt{37}$: hence

$$\frac{1}{k+1}\sqrt{25+25k^2}\leq \sqrt{37}$$

$$5\sqrt{1+k^2}\leq \sqrt{37}(k+1)$$
squaring

$$25\left(1+k^2\right)\le 37\left(k^2+2k+1\right)$$

Solving with Symbolab for example you have: $k\le -6\, \vee\, k\geq -\frac 16. $

Comment: Please let OP post their own attempt first.

Comment: I did a terrible mistake I assumed initial point of b vector to be the origin. And terminal point to divide the join.